# Excel VBA Macro: Using regex to return adjacent row data

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Alright; so here's the whole thing I'm suppose to do.

Input a number that corresponds with a number in Data Worksheet Column A and return the adjacent row data.

I want it to return the adjacent cells; example. If it finds 052035 in cell A5378, I Want it to return the data or cell numbers B5378, C5378

EDIT: I've deleted my code; since it didn't really follow with a good way to do it.

Worksheet Structure for Data:
A 1-7800ish[6 Digit number 1-9]

B 1-7800ish Area Codes

C 1-7800ish City/States

The data by the way; is a relatively large set that I got from a query on a SQL-Server. The string number that I'm looking for should have no duplicates based on my original query. [I grouped by before copying it over]

If ya'll have resources for a quick introduction to VB from a programming perspective that'll be helpful. I can program in C/C++ but the syntax in VB is a little weird to me.

Comment: So, what is your question?..

Comment: Your `Search` function is deliberately returning an empty string.

Comment: Moreover, you're not executing regex on strIn at all..

Comment: I will take all these questions and update my question accordingly.

Comment: Please also include more detail about your worksheet structure and what type of lookup you're actually trying to do. I think that maybe the range `.Find` or `.FindAll` method might be more appropriate.  Using RegEx to test whether an exact value exists in a range is not a good method to use. There are built in functions like `Match` that do that, just fine, and `VLOOKUP` which returns adjacent column data, etc.

Comment: Looked up the Match function; it seems to give a relative return value based on what the input was, is there any function that returns the absolute position - as in, which cell/column?

Comment: Using `Match` within VBA can do this by returning the relative position, and then determing that position's cell Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your end goal is to simply find the exact match in column A, and return the values in corresponding row, columns B & C, Regular Expressions is the wrong tool for the job.  Use built in functions like `Match`.

I still don't understand the point of this exercise, as, the data is already arranged in columns A, B and C., you could simply use AutoFilter...  This subroutine simply tells you that the value is found (and returns the corresponding data) or not found.

I have tested this (made a small change in dimensioning `vals` variable)

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim valToLookFor As String
    Dim rngToLookAt As Range
    Dim foundRow As Long
    Dim vals() As Variant

    valToLookFor = "052035"
    Set rngToLookAt = Range("A:A")

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(valToLookFor, rngToLookAt, False)) Then
        foundRow = Application.Match(valToLookFor, rngToLookAt, False)
        ReDim vals(1)
        vals(0) = rngToLookAt.Cells(foundRow).Offset(0, 1).Value
        vals(1) = rngToLookAt.Cells(foundRow).Offset(0, 2).Value

        'Alternatively, to return the cell address:
        'vals(0) = rngToLookAt.Cells(foundRow).Offset(0,1).Address
        'vals(1) = rngToLookAt.Cells(foundRow).Offset(0,2).Address
        MsgBox Join(vals, ",")
    Else:
        Erase vals
        MsgBox valToLookFor & " not found!", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

**Here is proof that it works:**

[image]

Comment: I'm adding a front end for the business people eventually. It's more of an "easy" exercise to get me to learn the tools I have to use at this job. Not doing so hot!

Comment: I ran into a type mismatch with the rngToLookAt as Range; I changed to String. Now I'm running into an object mismatched. I'm pretty sure it's a problem that I'm never telling it what Worksheet to read.

Comment: @user1741874 No worries about it, learning a new language takes some time. You will realize VBA is much more different from language you learned in univ like C or something :P It takes a bit of time to get used to all the tools provided by VBA. Not a fun language to play with in my honest opinion but doesn't take much time at all to get something done compared to other langs. (Of course, other people may tell me otherwise)

Comment: `rngToLookAt` should not be a string.  What specific error message when you do it as a `Range`?  It runs fine for me.

Comment: When unspecified, Excel assumes to look at the `ActiveSheet`.  Every worksheet has a column A, `Range("A:A")` is a valid range object on every sheet.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead an accept this as an the answer - I'm switching to another project for now and will study VB once I get home. Heads up - this doesn't work but at the same time I need  to learn more background information before I ask a question on this subject.

Comment: You're right! It does work. I just wasn't using the "scope" of VB correctly. Window placement matters etc. Very odd to me. Thanks so much for the help and double thanks for giving commented and easy to read code. This should help me get started.